# Prevent Collision Forces in Unity Physics in Collision Callback

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

How do I prevent a collision from applying forces in Unity? I am using 2D physics and want an arrow to stick into a crate. I can easily remove the rigid body and collider in the collision callback, but it seems that a frame of collision force is still applied to the arrow, causing slight jumps in position and rotation. Settings isKinematic on the rigid bodies in the collision callback also appears to not prevent this one frame of force being applied.

I am hoping to tell Unity to not apply physics for the collision.

Using kinematic for the life time of the arrow is not an option because the arrow needs to fly realistically until it hits something.

Here is the code for the crate object that handles the collision:

```
protected virtual void HandleCollision(ArrowScript arrow, Collision2D coll)
{
    StickArrow(arrow, coll);

    if (DestroyAfterSeconds >= 0.0f)
    {
        Destroy(arrow.gameObject, DestroyAfterSeconds);
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    ArrowScript script = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<ArrowScript>();
    if (script != null)
    {
        HandleCollision(script, coll);
    }
}

private bool StickArrow(ArrowScript arrow, Collision2D coll)
{
    Vector2 surfaceNormal = coll.contacts[0].normal;
    float surfaceAngle = Mathf.Atan2(surfaceNormal.y, surfaceNormal.x);
    float arrowAngle = Mathf.PI + (arrow.transform.eulerAngles.z * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float angleDifference = Mathf.Abs(BowAndArrowUtilities.DifferenceBetweenAngles(surfaceAngle, arrowAngle));
    float penetration = arrow.PercentPenetration * PenetrationPercentageModifier * (1.0f - angleDifference);
    if (penetration <= MinimumPenetrationPercentage)
    {
        arrow.PercentPenetration = 0.0f;
        return false;
    }

    // Make the arrow a child of the thing it's stuck to
    arrow.transform.parent = transform;
    arrow.gameObject.transform.Translate(new Vector3(-penetration * arrow.Length, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    SpriteRenderer thisSpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    if (thisSpriteRenderer != null)
    {
        arrow.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingLayerID = thisSpriteRenderer.sortingLayerID;
        arrow.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = Mathf.Max(0, thisSpriteRenderer.sortingOrder - 1);
    }

    BowAndArrowUtilities.PlayRandomSound(arrow.CollisionAudioClips, penetration * 5.0f);

    // destroy physics objects from the arrow (rigid bodies, colliders, etc.). This unfortunately doesn't prevent this frame from apply force (rotation, position) to the arrow.
    arrow.DestroyPhysicsObjects();

    return true;
}
```

Unity version is 5.3.4.

Comment: Have you tried checking use kinematic? I could be off but I think that might accomplish what you are looking for. look here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html

Comment: Setting kinematic prevents the arrow from flying through the air, so it's not an option. Setting isKinemtic in script after the collision has no effect on the jumpiness.

Comment: It is a bit of a hacky solution isn't it. Can you provide some of the code?

Comment: @mtrueblood I realized I can't use the trigger method because the collision now doesn't give me the normal of the collision. The arrow should only stick if it hits fairly dead on with a surface normal, not a side glancing blow.

Comment: Are you using Rigidbody.AddForce() or transform.position to move the arrow? Also is the target using a rigidbody, and if so what are the masses of both?

Comment: A simple workaround to have collisions without actual physical interaction between objects is to remove any colliders from the object but leave its rigidbody. Set its velocity or `AddForce()` to get the object moving. Then, using its previous position each physics calculation, perform a raycast from there to the object's current position. Your `RaycastHit` from the raycast should give the face normal if there is a hit, which you can then use in your collision handling. (Let me know if you need an example of this written out into code.)

Comment: @mtrueblood I am setting the arrow velocity once and letting it fly with the physics engine

Comment: @Serlite I think I will try your suggestion. I wish Unity made this easier in the collision callback, but for now your suggestion should work great. Seems odd they don't provide a way to tell the physics engine to ignore the collision.

Comment: "Seems odd they don't provide a way..." I alert you that when brand-new Unity hobbyists have opinions like this, you will often find it funny once you have basic experience (say, five years) with Unity.

Comment: @JoeBlow I've been making assets for two years, and been using Unity for four years. I don't know if that makes me a beginner, expert or whatever, but every other physics system I've used (chipmunk, farseer, etc.) has had a way to ignore collisions in the collision callback, preventing any kind of forces from happening.

Comment: are you looking for ***a trigger***, dude ??

Comment: @JoeBlow In the comments above I explained my attempt at a trigger, which unfortunately does not provide the collision data (normal, etc.) that I need.

Comment: there could just be some annoying thing, like, you're "turning off the physics" on the wrong "side" or in the wrong part of the frame you know? (and fair enough - that can be a huge nuisance in Unity until you "stumble on the right thing!")   I understand what you mean 100000% percent and have no trouble doing it as a matter of course.  perhaps it would be valuable to present your code/system for doing so .... ??

Comment: one thought.  as you know it's ubiquitous in games that you (surprisingly to "consumers") actually swap out the whole prefab for a different one at different times (like, going to a ragdoll, getting in a car - whatever).  In relation to the situation you describe, in some cases we do just that at the moment of contact.  just a thought to bear in mind.

Comment: @JoeBlow full code added to question. I'll look into swapping a prefab object, interesting idea.

Comment: right, i'm not saying that's the "general solution" but yah in unusual cases it works fantastically.  often in "gamey" "arcde" physics the behaviour (you could say mass, etc) drastically changes b4/after.  anyways...

Comment: @JoeBlow that is a great solution. You should answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making the arrow head a trigger. Inside of OnTriggerEnter2D, I then perform a circle cast in the direction the arrow is pointing with a width of the arrow head sprite. Triggers do not get affected by Unity physics calculations.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    ArrowScript script = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<ArrowScript>();
    if (script != null)
    {
        Vector2 dir = -script.ArrowHead.transform.right;

        // ray cast with the arrow size y value (thickness of arrow)
        RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.CircleCastAll(script.ArrowHead.transform.position, script.Size.y, dir);
        foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in hits)
        {
            // collider2d is a member variable assigned in Start that is the Collider2D for this object
            if (hit.collider == collider2d)
            {
                HandleCollision(script, hit.normal);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was going to tell you, but you figured out in time ;)
You should avoid calling GetComponent, try identifying with tags or other thing and then when you identify your collision then you try getcomponent. Always keep the performance in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that OnCollisionEnter and OnTriggerEnter are called after all the collisions are resolved.

The simplest way to solve this without affecting anything would be to change the weight of the box, arrow, or both.

Set the weight of the crate to a high value, and the weight of the arrow to a low value.

Another way is to use trigger colliders, as you have done. However trigger colliders have problematic side-effects. For example, it doesn't call OnCollisionEnter or OnTriggerEnter on the crate. You will have to do all the logic inside the arrow script, which is not much of a problem.

There are a lot of other ugly hacks however. You could set the velocity of the box to 0 after impact, but it would freeze the crate if you hit it as it was moving. You could use the collision information to cancel the force applied to the crate to solve the collision. You could save the last velocity of the crate every frame, and reapply it to the rigid body during the OnCollision call.

I wouldn't suggest any of these, but they are possible.